# 'Nonetype' object has no attribute 'insert', cannot understand why

Tags: python

I'm trying to take a list and reverse the middle elements only, not the first and last.  I keep running into a nonetype error and don't understand why.

```
def reverse_middle(nums):
    a = nums[0]
    b = nums[-1]
    interior = nums
    interior.pop()
    interior.pop(0)
    final = interior.reverse()
    final.insert(0, a)
    final.append(b)
    return final
```

Comment: Please include the stacktrace of the error, it will help us pinpoint where exactly the error is thrown.

Comment: Why did you expect a `None` object to have an attribute called `insert`?

Comment: haha its called nums and I manage to ask if its words I take its 3 numbers?

Answer (score 1):

The reverse method of `list` reverses the list but doesn't return the reversed list but `None` instead: the reverse is made in-place.

```
def reverse_middle(nums):
    a = nums[0]
    b = nums[-1]
    interior = nums
    interior.pop()
    interior.pop(0)
    interior.reverse()
    final = interior
    final.insert(0, a)
    final.append(b)
    return final
```

And for a more concise code use this:

```
def reverse_middle(nums):
    a = nums[0]
    b = nums[-1]
    interior = nums[1:-1]
    interior.reverse()
    final = [a] + interior + [b]
    return final
```

And even more concise

```
def reverse_middle(nums):
    interior = nums[1:-1]
    interior.reverse()
    return [nums[0]] + interior + [nums[-1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

`interior.reverse()` does so in-place (i.e. interior is reversed) and **returns nothing** to `final`.

That's why, final is None. None object has no method called `insert`.

Comment: If you want to make a reversed copy, `final = interior[::-1]` will do what the OP was trying to do.

Comment: is it just 3 words? never more? is that what you mean?